# How to set up the Twitter gem in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter

I have installed Ruby on Rails on my computer. I would like to create twitter API with Ruby on Rails.

I downloaded this gem zip file also:

[image]

I have Twitter API token and key.

I don't know how to move up.

Comment: How about reading the docs? https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Comment: sir thanks for your reply. i downloaded  and saved zip file on my pc.

Comment: i install the gem via command prompt. what shout i do now ? how to create this initializer ?

Comment: Why is there an image of a Stack Overflow question embedded into your question?

Comment: @Moumit: regarding your edit, bold can be a useful tool, but don't overuse it. It is better for just single words or phrases, not for whole sentences/paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to add the Twitter gem to your app:

1. Open your `Gemfile` and add this: `gem 'twitter', '~> 5.16'`
2. Type `bundle install` at the command line (making sure you're in the
   directory of your Rails app) and hit enter.

You should see some messages relating to gem installation.